# Which category "dropdown" is optimal for mobile/desktop for >10-15 items?

Tags: menu, dropdown

I have a menu, on the top, with a category dropdown. This is the only menu, which has a subitems. The main menu consists 4-5 item. Under categories will be 10-15 items aprox. Categories may have images/icons.

I'm thinking about three options, according to both UX and "fancy UI":

1. The classic dropdown. I know it's simple, well known, but feels a bit boring.
   [image: version 1]
2. Move down the whole content, slide down the top bar to display categories. It's not so boring, but could looks a bit odd with a narrow list.
   [image: version 2]
3. Categories display next to each other, with sliding down menu.
   [image: version 3]

Looking for:

- Working on mobile/desktop
- Easy to use, overview with 10-15 items (ex.: horizontal version not seems good for mobile)
- Not so classic solution

Feel free to suggest any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to consider is dividing those 15 items in groups so each group have maximum 5 items
Information should be easier to digest in small chunks rather than showing list of 15 items

I searched for different patterns on Google and found out few that might interest you

1) [Yamm MegaMenu Accordian](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/) and List style dropdowns

[image: list drop down megamenu]
[image: accordian drop down menu]

2) [CodyHouse Mega site Navigation](http://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-site-navigation/index.html)
[image]

Hope my answer helps you

Comment: Thx, Categories won't be hierarchical, its like finance, healthcare, sport, childcare. Both is inspiring btw, I think I will go on with version 2!

Comment: Keep in mind though that Information is easier to scan top to bottom and left to right.....You can also analyze how user interact with your sub-menu  items and move the ones at top which are used the most...